# NSSavePanel issues

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nssavepanel

I am semi-new to cocoa programming, however I have worked quite a bit in C++;

I am having some issues with the NSSavePanel class. Whenever I use it (as shown below), I can see (by using breakpoints) that the code tries to execute the ending bracket. I then get a BAD_ACCESS message from Xcode in the main.h file. I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
- (void)scannerDevice:(ICScannerDevice*)scanner didCompleteScanWithError:(NSError*)error;
{
    NSLog( @"scannerDevice: \n%@\ndidCompleteScanWithError: \n%@\n", scanner, error );
    [mProgressIndicator setHidden:YES];

    NSSavePanel *savePopup = [[NSSavePanel alloc]init];
    [savePopup runModal];

    NSMutableString *saveString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    saveString = [[savePopup URL] absoluteString];
    [saveString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 16)];
    [saveString appendString:@".jpeg"];

    NSLog(@"[[ADDRESS: %@", saveString); //Outputs /Users/tannerdsilva/Documents/TestFolder/NewName.jpeg
    NSError *errorSave = [[NSError alloc] init];

    [manager moveItemAtPath:[@"~/Foo.jpeg" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] toPath:[[savePopup URL] absoluteString] error:&errorSave]; // ~/Foo.jpeg does exist

    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", errorSave);
    [saveString dealloc];
    [savePopup dealloc];

}
```

When I hard code the new destination and remove the NSSavePanel, I don't get any crashes.

Thank you ahead of time, and I apologize if this is a simple fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

- You declare `saveString` as an `NSMutableString` but initialize it as an (immutable) `NSString`.
- You're then not using that string at all but replace it with the autoreleased (and immutable) `NSString` that's returned from `absoluteString`, causing the original string to leak.
- `NSString` responds to neither `deleteCharactersInRange:` nor to `appendString` (those are methods of `NSMutableString`).
- You're leaking `errorSave` which you should initialize as `nil` anyway.
- You should *never ever* call `dealloc` yourself, use `release` instead. But don't release `saveString` because it's already autoreleased (see above), you're over-releasing it here which will cause a crash when the autorelease pool is drained.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there's a couple problems with your code:

---

***Method signature has a trailing semi-colon***

```
(void)scannerDevice:(ICScannerDevice*)scanner didCompleteScanWithError:
    (NSError*)error;
```

***EDIT***: Per @omz and @Rudy Velthuis, a trailing semi-colon on an implementation method signature is allowed by Objective-C. So you can ignore this 'problem'.

---

***You should use the class instance for getting handle to save panel***

```
NSSavePanel * savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
```

---

***You should check the result of running the save panel modally***

```
if ([savePanel runModal] == NSOKButton) {
    //...
}
```

---

***You are creating an instance of NSString * and leaking it, totally unnecessary***

```
NSMutable * saveString = [NSMutableString stringWithString: 
   [[savePopup URL] absoluteString]];
```

---

Once you correct the problems outlined above, you will want to remove the two dealloc lines, since the objects will now be autoreleased. Note that you normally want to call *release* in your code anyway, not *dealloc*.

Comment: That is not a syntax error. In fact, it's more convenient to have a semicolon at the end of the signature because it can be copied as-is to the header this way.

Comment: Those floating semicolons are allowed, though, because it makes copying and pasting from the `@interface` section a lot easier.

Comment: @omz: Or the other way around: *from* the header. I usually write the header first.

Comment: @Rudy: Right, copying from the header is probably more common.

Comment: Interesting, I guess you learn something new every day. I can't imagine writing method signatures in my implementation file that way though, it irritates the inner C coder in me.